# __cplusplus expanded minimum values

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++03, c++98

Am I right to understand that these are the **minimum** values of `__cplusplus` and that C++98 has the same value has C++03?

```
// C++ 98
#define __cplusplus 199711L
// C++ 03
#define __cplusplus 199711L
// C++ 11
#define __cplusplus 201103L
// C++ 14
#define __cplusplus 201402L
// C++ 17
#define __cplusplus 201500L
// C++ 20
#define __cplusplus 201704L
// looks like the format is YEAR*100+something
```

Also, does C++20 have an official value now that the standard is released?

Comment: Is it too early to start panicking over the naming scheme not being Y10K compliant?

Comment: @user4581301 maybe not! leading zeros would make the number octal, so it is Y10K compliant.

Comment: @user4581301 Given that it's not fixed-width? Yes :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Also, does C++20 have an official value now that the standard is released?

It does: [`202002L`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.1). The format here is a date: YYYYMM (C++20 was made official in February 2020). The value for C++17 was 201703L, not 201500. All the rest are correct (C++03 did not change the `__cplusplus` macro).

However, this macro is far too coarse to be generally useful. Implementations don't just add every feature in one go, they get added as time progresses. So you're better off using [feature-test macros](https://wg21.link/sd6) to test for what you actually need.

Comment: I would just like to know their value as of the final release of that standard. It's necessary and useful for what I'm doing